# I'm always getting 301 HTTP header code even if the image doesn't exist on server (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to figure out if a Image of a user exists or not. If the user image doesn't exist, it should give me a '404 Not Found' in the headers, but i'm always getting a '301 Moved Permanently', even if the user image doesn't exist! Can you help me ?
here is my code

```
    <?php 
    $filename='profile-picture-' .$request->id . '.jpg' . '?=' . rand(); // this picture doesn't  exist 
    $filePath=storage_url_profile_photo("helper/profile\\$filename");
    $filePath = str_replace('\\','/', $filePath);
    
    echo $filePath;
    $file_headers = @get_headers($filePath);
    echo $file_headers[0];
    if($file_headers[0] !== 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
      echo "exists";
    } else {
      echo "not exists";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache or try opening the image in a different browser

Comment: how about `.htaccess` rules?

Comment: it was working well before , nothing changed in code but from today morning i am facing this issue, on localhost it is working fine .